# After trigger('create') JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

To force the DOM layout refresh I trigger the 'create' event by

```
$(elem).trigger('create')
```

syntax. I need to execute a callback on the page refresh done event. Is there an event triggered by the JQM engine when the page was refreshed?

I can't find nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Such callback function don't exist.

Thou you can use jQuery Mobile page event called pafeshow, it will trigger after everything is enhanced and visible:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#paegID', function(){ 

});
```